# $q, deferred and partial application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

So I'm wondering why this doesn't work as expected:

```
fn = ->
   dfrd = $q.defer()
   $timeout ->
      dfrd.resolve({foo:'bar'})
    ,1000
    return dfrd.promise


displayData = (data)-> 
   console.log(data.foo)

fn().then(displayData)                  # doesn't work like that

fn().then((data)-> displayData(data))   # works if used like this - prints "bar"
```

So why `then` doesn't get properly curried?

Comment: What do you mean by "curried"? There is no difference from CS perspective. Can you provide a demo that shows what doesn't work?

Comment: You know what? Actually it does work http://plnkr.co/edit/pX4KV1gfTH6v6jXcUCP3?p=preview , there's something probably wrong in my actual code :(

Answer (score -1):

`.then(cb)` is the signature, not `.then(data)`.

You need to pass a callback that gets the data as an argument:

`.then(function(data){ //use data here });`

Comment: That's what I'm saying: why can't you use it: `.then(displayData)` where `displayData` is a function that has signature needed for the callback? It's suppose to be firing it and passing any arguments that returned with the promise, right?

Comment: I don't really know what that drivel is you posted there. But `.then` needs a function. you are passing an object.

Comment: What are you talking about? `var fn = function(arg){ console.log(arg) };   foo.then(fn)` where do you see an object?